# Random background with php & css

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am trying to have different background loads for every page view. Not only rotate the image with a refresh. I have a code that works, but only on refresh. I believe I can fix this by using a script or a get template function instead but I've tried many, many scripts and snippets that I've found online and nothing works. I would really appreciate some guidance on this. I've tried and have given up on this a few times over the last couple of years and I'd love to find a resolution. Thank you in advance for any advice.

This is my PHP code, it is placed in the same directory with my rotating images:

```
<?php

$folder = '.';

$extList = array();
$extList['gif'] = 'image/gif';
$extList['jpg'] = 'image/jpeg';
$extList['jpeg'] = 'image/jpeg';
$extList['png'] = 'image/png';

$img = null;

if (substr($folder,-1) != '/') {
    $folder = $folder.'/';
}

if (isset($_GET['img'])) {
    $imageInfo = pathinfo($_GET['img']);
    if (
        isset( $extList[ strtolower( $imageInfo['extension'] ) ] ) &&
        file_exists( $folder.$imageInfo['basename'] )
    ) {
        $img = $folder.$imageInfo['basename'];
    }
} else {
    $fileList = array();
    $handle = opendir($folder);
    while ( false !== ( $file = readdir($handle) ) ) {
        $file_info = pathinfo($file);
        if (
            isset( $extList[ strtolower( $file_info['extension'] ) ] )
        ) {
            $fileList[] = $file;
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);

    if (count($fileList) > 0) {
        $imageNumber = time() % count($fileList);
        $img = $folder.$fileList[$imageNumber];
    }
}

if ($img!=null) {
    $imageInfo = pathinfo($img);
    $contentType = 'Content-type: '.$extList[ $imageInfo['extension'] ];
    header ($contentType);
    readfile($img);
} else {
    if ( function_exists('imagecreate') ) {
        header ("Content-type: image/png");
        $im = @imagecreate (100, 100)
            or die ("Cannot initialize new GD image stream");
        $background_color = imagecolorallocate ($im, 255, 255, 255);
        $text_color = imagecolorallocate ($im, 0,0,0);
        imagestring ($im, 2, 5, 5,  "IMAGE ERROR", $text_color);
        imagepng ($im);
        imagedestroy($im);
    }
}

?>
```

This is my CSS code

```
    body.page-boxed-bg {
    background-image: url(https://www.website.com/wp-content/themes/theme-child/images/backgrounds/rotate.php);
}
```

Comment: Your browser will cache the results. So it will only refresh the image with a hard-reload. Instead, use PHP directly in the body (and not through CSS `url()`) to add the image.

Comment: Thank you for your response Qirel. I'm not sure how to do that...do you think you could explain a little more or share a reference? Thank you again.

Comment: You can add random string (like timestamp) after your url to prevent it from caching. like : `...rotate.php?t=13464794645`

Comment: Indeed you can, but how do you plan on doing that in a .css file? I can not think of a way to achieve it at least.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion ttrasn, I tried that but it has no effect.

Comment: @joy Did your number is random and auto generated ?

Comment: Hi @ttrasn, I added what you suggested right into my css. Am I doing that incorrectly?